# Unicorn! and PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, unicorn

I am in the middle of upgrading an old Rails and PostgreSQL app from 2.1 to Rails 3 (via a successful intermediate 2.3.11 step).

Finally, when I got all the Rspecs running smoothly, I installed Mongrel 1.2.0.pre2 and got it up and running - all OK. Even the JMeter test case with 100 concurrent users passed OK.

But when I tried the same with Unicorn! server, it works fine when I am using it myself, but when I get it under load with JMeter, it starts giving 100% errors from the moment, where JMeter tries to POST a login. At the same time when I check some specific page, it gives me weird errors like this:

```
undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass
```

At the terminal I get the following output (but only a few times):

```
message type 0x43 arrived from server while idle
message type 0x5a arrived from server while idle
WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
```

**EDIT: this seems to be an issue with shared `PGconnect` object, so I removed some of previous text**

I found that [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/libpq-threading.html) specify that `PGconn` object must not be shared between threads making concurrent requests.

Is Unicorn! or AR mixing requests from different threads in the same `PGconn` object?

Database.yml:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: ***
  username: ***
  password: ***
  host: 127.0.0.1
```

I even tried to add this to no avail:

```
  allow_concurrency: true
```

unicorn.conf:

```
worker_processes 8
working_directory "/full/path/to/app"
listen '/tmp/app.sock', :backlog => 512
timeout 30
pid "/full/path/to/app/tmp/pids/puppetmaster_unicorn.pid"

preload_app true
  if GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=)
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true
end
```

Specs:

- Rails 3.0.6 (because of deployment env)
- Unicorn! 4.1.1
- Nginx 1.0.5
- pg gem 0.11.0
- PostgreSQL 9.0.4
- Mac OS X 10.7.2

If Rails version should be the culprit, of course I can upgrade to the latest. I just started off with what the service provider has.

Comment: How many unicorn workers do you create in unicorn.rb? What timeout?

Comment: I updated my question with unicorn.conf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's critical not to share database connections between processes. When you run Rails with preload_app Rails will establish the AR connection(s) before the unicorn master forks the workers. The example unicorn.conf.rb has a recommendation to disconnect the AR connection in the before_fork hook. AR will automatically reestablish a fresh connection as each worker requires it post-fork.

excerpt from http://unicorn.bogomips.org/examples/unicorn.conf.rb:

```
before_fork do |server, worker|
  # the following is highly recomended for Rails + "preload_app true"
  # as there's no need for the master process to hold a connection
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Yes, I found out that too, with help from Unicorn mailing-list, but forgot to update my answer. I award points to you for doing this for me. Thank you.